# Login failed while adding the functionality of Google+ Login

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-volley, google-signin, android-googleapiclient

I have added the functionality of the Google+ login. But when I am clicking on the button of the login it is coming to the else condition block and hence login failed. i can't understand whats wrong I am doing the code? I am attaching the code of the login functionality

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    //Signin button
    private SignInButton signInButton;

    //Signing Options
    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

    //google api client
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    //Signin constant to check the activity result
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

    //TextViews
    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewEmail;
    private NetworkImageView profilePhoto;

    //Image Loader
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        profilePhoto = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        //Initializing google signin option
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        //Initializing signinbutton
        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        //Initializing google api client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();


        //Setting onclick listener to signing button
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    //This function will option signing intent
    private void signIn() {
        //Creating an intent
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

        //Starting intent for result
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //If signin
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            //Calling a new function to handle signin
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }


    //After the signing we are calling this function
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        //If the login succeed
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //Getting google account
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            //Displaying name and email
            textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
            textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());

            //Initializing image loader
            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                    .getImageLoader();

            imageLoader.get(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

            //Loading image
            profilePhoto.setImageUrl(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);

        } else {
            //If login fails
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == signInButton) {
            //Calling signin
            signIn();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

**CustomVolleyRequest.java**

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;


    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }

}
```

**activitymain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.googlelogin.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:text="email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Pls try my Github repo at https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleSignInDemo, of course with your google-services.json. Some useful links https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating and https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: This seems like an authentication issue. What does your error log say?

Anyway here's a link to a fully functional [Google-Sign demo](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin). You need to provide your own google-services.json and configure your GDC(package name, SHA1, API Key , oauth Client IDs) as specified in the [Android Sign-in Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start).